# Is there a widget/service to put a marker and send data?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, web

I need to ask people where they want to go in the city, and as a response I need either geocoded location, or a marker on a map. Although everyone knows his home address, not everyone knows the address of a building they go to, most likely they don't.

So, the best option, I think, would be a slippy map integrated in a web page.

Is there such a reusable widget for Leaflet/OpenLayers or proprietary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two plugins for Leaflet that you can use:

[**Leaflet draw**](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw)

It adds support for putting markers on a map. This way your users simply can put down a marker at the place where they want to go to.

**[Leaflet geosearch](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch)**

It adds support to lookup address based on OSM, Google, and ESRI. This way your user can write down general locations, and a marker will be put down on the location. It doesn't have to be a exact address. Things like `Empire State Building` will work too.